# samba shows `NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME'

Tags: samba

We have a samba config that we were using for at least two years. That config includes

```
[global]

unix extensions = no
wide links = yes
```

Testing that config with

```
smbclient -L <IP>
```

shows

```
NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME
```

If we comment one of those lines and reload smbd, we can access our shares again. However, symlinks are not being followed.

**Version:**

```
dpkg -s samba | grep -i version
```

shows `2:4.13.17`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer turned out to be to install `samba-vfs-modules`. In Samba 4.13, the  ability to follow wide links was pushed to this module.

Reference: https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/vfs_widelinks.8.html